# In my Blazor server app I have a razor page with iframe that includes a pdf. I want that the pdf is opened at a specific line including a string

Tags: pdf, iframe, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server app I have a razor page with an iframe that includes a pdf file. The pdf file is containing the definition of appr. 2000 CNC variables. The razor page will be opened for the explanation of the CNC variable that is selected in another page. I want that the razor page is opened at the correct line where the related parameter is explained.

How can I do that without defining destinations, because this would take too much time. I would have to define 2000 destinations in the pdf. I can assume that the full parameter name is included in just one line in the document, so I have to open the pdf at the first line where the parameter definition appears. How is that possible?

Here I select the parameter

```
@page "/Par_selection"
@inject DialogService DialogService
<select value="@Cnc_Par_selected" @onchange="Open_PDF">

   for (int r = 0; r < Sys_Var_Data.BAG_area.Count; r++)
   {
     <option>@Parameter_List[r]</option>                       
   }
</select>
@code
{      

public void Open_PDF()
{           
   await DialogService.OpenAsync<Cnc_Par_PDF>("CNC Parameters", options: new DialogOptions { CloseDialogOnOverlayClick = true, ShowTitle = true,  Width = "1500px", Height = "800px", Style = "left:200px; padding:0px" });
}
```

Here I show the pdf file in an iframe

```
@page "/Cnc_Par_PDF"

  <iframe src="/files/Cnc_Par.pdf" width="1500" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could modify your Razor page to open the PDF at a specific

```
@page "/Sys_VAR_PDF"
@using System.IO;

<body> 
    <iframe src="/files/SysVAR/sysvar_sl_uni.pdf#page=5" width="1500" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that I don't the page numbers for all the 2000 parameter definitions. It would take too much time to do that.